# Set back the default style to a button programmatically

Tags: android, button, background, styles, default

I've changed button color

```
btnBackground.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
```

but I can't find how to turn back the default button style

Comment: `btnBackground.setColorFilter(null);`

Answer (score 1):

Try `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` or `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER`:

```
// PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER is the default
btnBackground.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```